# How to choose random word in python from a list of words

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

This is my code:

```
rightPath = random.choice(North,East,South,West)

if selectPath == rightPath:
    print("You slay the monsterous beast and proceed further into the castle")
    print("This is just the start of your dangerous adventure")
else:
    print("The Monster attacks leaving you helpless on the floor")
    time.sleep(4)
    print("You Died")
```

I want to make it choose a random direction from the list of North, East, South, West.

Comment: are you sure `North,East,South,West` is a list?  `random.choice` expects a list as a parameter.

Answer (score 3):

[`random.choice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice) expects a sequence as a parameter.

So you might probably use:

```
rightPath = random.choice(['North', 'East', 'South', 'West'])
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do it (you'll just have to replace `selectPath` with your input:

```
rightPath = random.choice(['North','East','South','West'])
selectPath = 'North'
if selectPath == rightPath:
    print("You slay the monsterous beast and proceed further into the castle")
    print("This is just the start of your dangerous adventure")
else:
    print("The Monster attacks leaving you helpless on the floor")
    time.sleep(4)
    print("You Died")
```